# qTip that stays open

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip

Is it possible to create a tooltip that would stay open, even when mouse isn't hovering underlying element anymore?

I'm trying to change `fixed` to true and in `beforeHide` return false. That's not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for qTip somehow obscure. So basically it has to be called like that:

```
$(".mydiv").qtip(
                 api: {
                        beforeHide: function () {
                                return false;
                         }
                      },
                 hide: { fixed: true }
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the "hide:" property blank (but you have to list it). For example:

```
show: 'mousehover',
hide: ''
...
```

Basically, it's waiting for an event literally named an empty string, which will never happen.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this on all browsers, but I can vouch for Chrome. If you do a lot of testing, it'd be nice if you share the results!

Comment: Although throws Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in the console

Comment: Agzam: Hmm I'm not getting that in Chrome on 13.0.782.55 beta, with 1rc3 of qtip. Any major version differences?

The other thing you might want to try is putting in a string for the event like 'neverExecute'. I use qTip with some custom events to which I invoke with jquery.trigger(). I assume if you never trigger, they'll never show. Certainly does not give an error when i trigger using a custom event, so i can't imagine never referencing it would cause an error...

Comment: instead of an empty string, try setting "hide" parameter to false.